# What is the origin of the idiom "Put a pin in it"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms, phrase-origin

Does anyone have a definitive origin for the phrase/idiom "Put/stick a pin in it/that" used to mean "let's delay, come back to something later"?

I searched the site, but didn't see this asked or answered.

---

Possible origins I've found or considered:

- Urban Dictionary (sorry) offers a WWII origin of putting the pin back in a grenade so it doesn't explode.
- Multiple sources mention Jane Austen's use of pins to mark edits in her manuscript but I don't know if this was a wide enough practice to coin a phrase.
- I can easily picture this coming from the tailoring trade (as so many idioms did) where you pin fabric in position before sewing it down.
- Wikipedia offers this on the [history of the drawing pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_pin#History) or push pin (with some great detail about their effect on woodwork):

  > The drawing pin was invented in name and as a mass-produced item in what is now the United States in the mid/late 1750s. It was first mentioned in the Oxford English Dictionary in 1759. It was said that the use of the newly invented drawing pin to attach notices to school house doors was making significant contribution to the whittling away of their gothic doors. Modern drawing pins were also found as standard in architects’ drawing boxes in the late 18th century.
  >
  > Edwin Moore patented the "push-pin" in the US in 1900 and founded the Moore Push-Pin Company. Moore described them as a pin with a handle. Later, in 1903, in Lychen, German clockmaker Johann Kirsten invented flat-headed pins for use with drawings.

  Given this, I would say an occurrence of the phrase pre-1750 makes an origin in the sewing trades more likely?

  There is another occurrence in the [Wikipedia entry on (standard/straight) pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin#Sewing_and_fashion_pins) mentioning their use in marking or pinning together pages of a book, so maybe this was a common enough practice to coin the phrase.
- Searching for the phrase "stick a pin" (between 1700 and 1850) in Google Books turned up the following occurrences:

  - 1821 – The phrase appears in William Cobbett's column "To Mr. John Hayes, on Lawyer Scarlett's Poor-Law Bill" from his newspaper *Cobbett's Weekly Political Register* on May 14, 1821 (republished in 1835 in [*Selections from Cobbett's Political Works*, Volume 6, p. 87)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-kRjAAAAcAAJ&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22#v=onepage&f=false)). Cobbett writes:

    > [...] at the same time, made grand military preparations, not leaving out the *cannons*. What *law* they had for these things a day may come, perhaps, for inquiring in a lawful way. At present, we will "*stick a pin there*." Fasten so much up in your and my memory: and in the meanwhile [...]

    The quotation marks appear in the original texts (which suggests to me an early idiomatic use).
  - 1826 – William Cobbett also used the phrase again in his column "Rural Ride, from Burghclere to Lyndhurst, in the New Forest", which was first published in the *Political Register* on October 21, 1826 (and republished in 1826 in his book [*Rural Rides*, p. 557](https://books.google.com/books?id=0gsHAAAAQAAJ&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22#v=onepage&f=false)):

    > The sales of sheep, at this one fair (including Appleshaw), must have amounted, this year, to *a hundred and twenty or thirty thousand pounds less than last year*! Stick a pin there, master "PROSPERITY ROBINSON," and turn back to it again anon! [...]

    This, with further elaboration of "turn[ing] back to it again", supports the explanation of a pin used to mark a place in a book.

Comment: Attempts to answer (or guess at the answer to) the question should probably be posted as an answer, instead of edited into the question. And in general, when you edit a question, it should read as if it were always the best version of itself, rather than simply tacking an "EDIT:" note at the end.

Answer (score 9):

In 1859, the book ["Nature and Human Nature"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BvTe33Vl5TkC&pg=PA47&dq=%22stick%20a%20pin%20in%20it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmpuqM2qvnAhWColwKHesUD2EQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20in%20it%22&f=false) by Thomas Chandler Haliburton included the phrase "Stick a pin in it", in a somewhat figurative manner that alludes to keeping something set apart to refer back to in the future.

The Doctor has just said "*God has made sunny spots in the heart; why should we exclude the light from them?*"

The narrator replies, "*Stick a pin in that, Doctor, for it's worth rememberin' as a wise saw.*"

The passage also suggests an origin of the phrase, related to the preserving of insects by an entomologist, by literally sticking a pin in it.

There may be other origins, but this is the earliest figurative use of the phrase I've found.

> "[...] Oh, you would make a new man of me soon, I am sure you would, if I was any time with you. I haven't laughed before that way for many a long day. Oh, it does me good. There is nothing like fun, is there? I haven't any myself, but I do like it in others. Oh, we need it. We need all the counterweights we can muster to balance the sad relations of life. *God has made many sunny spots in the heart; why should we exclude the
> light from them?*"
>
> "Stick a pin in that, Doctor," says I, "for it's worth rememberin' as a wise saw."
>
> He then took up his wallet, and retired to his room to change
> his clothes, saying to himself, in an under-tone: "Stick a pin in it. What a queer phrase; and yet it's expressive, too. It's the way I preserve my insects."

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the early reference! I hadn't thought of insect mounting as an origin at all. That explanation may be a quirk/idiosyncrasy of the character though. This text example does take it back much further than the grenade/pin concept (which couldn't have been earlier than ~1915 according to the wikipedia entry on grenades).

Answer (score 4):

***'Stick a pin there' in England***

[*The Vocal Companion: Or, Songster's Universal Magazine: Being a Collection of All the New Celebrated Songs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BGXOpP0-RtsC&pg=PA20&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZyZ7K1dvsAhURrp4KHey1CMMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1770) offers a popular song built around the first literal and then figurative expression "stick a pin there":

> ***Stick a Pin There.*** *Sung at* Sadler's Wells.
>
> When tutor'd by mother, she oftentimes aid, / There's money bid for thee, girl, hold up thy had; / She laid out my work with a housewifely care, / And, makin a mark, bid me **stick a pin there**. / Stick a pin, &c.
>
> The humour so pleas'd me, however absurd, / That, in spight of my teeth, it became a cant word; / And once, when the parson had ended his pray'r, / I could not help calling out, **stick a pin there**. / Stick a pin, &c.
>
> He came to my mother, and loudly complin'd: / His pardon I ask'd, but my sorrow was feign'd; / And before he could clap his fat bum in a chair, / I slily stoop'd down, and did **stick a pin there**. / Stick a pin, &c.
>
> I met my dear Jack in a field a new hay, /He kiss'd me and teas'd me with amorous play; / A green gown he gave me, and swore it was fair: / Hold, sirrah, said I, would you **stick a pin there**? / Stick a pin, &c.
>
> He often attempted to ruffle my charms, / As often I push'd the dear youth from my arms; / But sooner or later he'll baffle my care, / For Jack is the lad---but **stick a pin there**. / Stick a pin, &c.

The same song appears in [*The Syren: A Choice Collection of the Most Esteemed and Favourite Songs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hzVYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZyZ7K1dvsAhURrp4KHey1CMMQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1770) and again in [*The Choice Spirit's Chaplet: Or, a Poesy from Parnassus*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DcIUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA247&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZyZ7K1dvsAhURrp4KHey1CMMQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1771), where the final line of the fifth verse is given as "For Jack is the lad that shall---**stick a pin there**."

Interestingly a collection from ten years earlier—[*The Nightingale. Being a Choice Collection of the Newest and Most Favourite English Songs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=J_xeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZyZ7K1dvsAhURrp4KHey1CMMQ6AEwCHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1760)—includes a song titled "Stick a Pin There," although the phrase does not appear in the lyrics of the song itself, which is about conveying one's intentions with a wink.

Also from 1760 is this instance from [*The Ladies and Gentlemens Musical Memorandum: Or, Norfolk Songster*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nvzuNCqFSPoC&pg=PA31&dq=%22stick+a+pin+there%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH2Kq04dvsAhUgFjQIHUAJCHAQ6AEwA3oECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22&f=false) (1760):

> *(**Stick a Pin there**.)*
>
> And then to the Tower away we all stroll'd, / The lyons, the armour, and crown to behold; / When the shew-man, at last, bid the lasses so fair / In old Harry's pincushion **stick a pin there**.

This same song snippet appears in [*The Musical Miscellany: Or, Songster's Companion*](https://books.google.com/books?id=46pXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA159&dq=%22stick+a+pin+there%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH2Kq04dvsAhUgFjQIHUAJCHAQ6AEwBHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22&f=false) (1789) and in [*The Universal Songster, Or Harmony and Innocence: An Elegant and Polite Selection of Modern and Approved Songs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PTJYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA306&dq=%22stick+a+pin+there%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0tIqJ4NvsAhXGJzQIHcKDDsIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22&f=false) (1800).

An earlier use of the phrase "stick a pin" occurred in connection with an exaggeration about overcrowding: "no room to stick a pin." This appears at least as early as the preface to George Farquhar, [*The Inconstant; or, The Way to Win Him*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XoI0AAAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA8&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmsMiw3NvsAhXCoFsKHZ2OBIo4ChDoATAAegQIABAC#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1736):

> What can be a greater Compliment to our generous Nation, than to have the Lady upon her *retour* to *Paris*, boast of their splendid Entertainment in *England*, of the Complaisance, Liberality, and Good-nature of a People, that thronged her House so full , that she had not room to **stick a Pin**; and left a poor Fellow, that had the Misfortune of being one of themselves, without one Farthing for half a Year's Pains that he had taken for their Entertainment?

---

***'Stick a pin there' in the United States***

Richard Thornton, [*An American Glossary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rokVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA858&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip5b_u4tvsAhWfFjQIHZxHCkMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (1912) has this useful summary of U.S. instances of the expression (the first of which is also cited in *Green's Dictionary of Slang*, as noted in user121863's answer):

> **Stick a pin there.** Make a note of that.
>
> **1836** Why does money become scarce? Because the bankers cannot discount, says the merchant. ***Stick a pin there***.—Phila[delphia] *Public Ledger*, Nov. 1.
>
> **1842** Heading of an advt., "***Stick a pin there***."—Phila[delphia] *Spirit of the Times*, April 16.
>
> **1843** ***Stick a pin there*** and consider.—Nauvoo *Neighbor*, July 12.
>
> **1850** I wish to be honorable. *Tie a knot there*. I branded you for a cheat, a brute, and a coward; ***put a pin in there!*** I cannot blacken you—you are too black already; ***put a spike in there***!—S. Judd, 'Richard Edney,' pp. 100–101.
>
> **1861** Mr. Bell will not be chosen as one of Mr. Lincoln's cabinet. Let the guessers stick a pin there.—*Oregon Argus*, Jan. 19.
>
> **1861** Name for name, there are two of the Norman in New-England for one in the South. Stick a pin there—not that it's of any account, but the chivalry insist on it.—*Knick[erbocker] Mag[azine]* lviii. 266 (Sept.)

Instances in U.S. newspapers go back considerably farther than 1836, however. From "[Communication [?]](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=AGCP18130309.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22stick+a+pin+there%22-------),"in the *Alexandria [Virginia] Gazette, Commercial and Political* (March 9, 1813):

> He [James Madison(?)] goes on to say that "in carrying on the war, no principle of justice or honor, no usage of civilized nations, no precept of courtesy or humanity have been infringed." **Stick a pin there**, while we look back a little at Hull’s sugar proclamation. We find him there *trying* to do a deed so repugnant to "justice and honor," so counter to the "usage of civilized nations," so void of "courtesy or humanity," that even Bonaparte, great as were his extremities in Russia, and *intreated* as he was by the villagers to be armed against their own country, turned pale with horror at their suggestion (see his reply to the Senate.)

From an [untitled item](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=PG18310325.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22stick+a+pin+there%22-------) reproduced from the *Globe*, quoting the *Telegraph*, reprinted in the *[Alexandria, Virginia] Phenix Gazette* (March 25, 1831):

> "A spunky fellow this!" He says—'We hereby release all persons whatever from any injunction of secrecy, and defy Mr. Kendall to produce a single letter, or adduce a single conversation, however confidential, which will sustain his charge.'
>
> **Stick a pin there**!

From an [untitled item](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=AG18340111.1.2&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22stick+a+pin+there%22-------) in the *Alexandria [Virginia] Gazette* (January 11, 1834):

> We are surprised—perfectly surprised, at the astonishment expressed by some of our cotemporaries at the recent *waking up* of our old friend of the Richmond Enquirer, on the subject of Proscription. This sort of amazement will most assuredly put him to sleep again—or, at least, make him play ’possum. Now our rule is, always to deal gently with him—to use no scary expressions: when we catch him saying a good thing, we just **stick a pin there**, and go off to something else. By and by, when we have stuck a great many pins, we’ll show him what’s what.

Other early instances appear in the [*Pontiac [Michigan] Courier*](https://digmichnews.cmich.edu/cgi-bin/michigan?a=d&d=OaklandPONTC18361003-01.1.3&txq=%22stick+a+pin+there%22) (October 3, 1836), in the [*Richmond [Indiana] Palladium*](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=RPW18370826.1.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22stick+a+pin+there%22------) (August 26, 1837), in the [*Carlisle [Pennsylvania] Herald and Expositor*](https://panewsarchive.psu.edu/lccn/sn86071296/1838-10-05/ed-1/) (October 5, 1838), in the [*[Bowling Green, Missouri] Salt River Journal*](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83016924/1840-05-02/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22stick%2Ba%2Bpin%2Bthere%22) (May 2, 1840), and in the [*New-York Mirror*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bX5NAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22stick+a+pin%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjeoobu5tvsAhXiMn0KHfGhCog4FBDoATACegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%22&f=false) (August 1, 1840).

William Thurston, [*Guide to the Gold Regions of Upper California](https://books.google.com/books?id=2GNZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA41&dq=%22stick+a+pin+there%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii2qqf6NvsAhUgITQIHUDeBmoQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20a%20pin%20there%22&f=false) (1849), quoting "a resident of Monterey [California]," has a particularly elaborate rendition of the phrase:

> I know seven men who worked seven weeks and two days, Sundays excepted, on Feather River; they employed on an average fifty Indians, and got out in these seven weeks and two days 275 lb. of pure gold. I know the men and have seen the gold, and know what they state to be a fact,—so **stick a pin there**. I know ten other men who worked ten days in company, employed no Indians, and averaged in those ten days, 1500 dollars each,—so **stick another pin there**. I know another man who got out of a basin in a rock, not larger than a washbowl, 2½ lb of gold in fifteen minutes,—so **stick another pin there**.

---

***Conclusions***

"Stick a pin there" was already in use as a popular song title in 1760 in England, and a 1770 song of that name shows the term being used both literally and figuratively as the punch line of each verse.

Figurative use of the expression in the United States goes back at least to 1813, where, even at that early date, it seems to have been understood to mean "make a note of [something]."

The distance between "make a note of [something]" and "set [something] aside for future consideration" is not particularly large, so I would not be surprised if the latter meaning emerged out the former (and earlier) one. The connection between the English "stick a pin there" of the eighteenth and early nineteenth century and the U.S. "stick a pin there" of 1813 and of the 1830s and later is less obvious, but circumstantially it is very tempting to infer that the English expression emigrated to the United States and began a new life there with a somewhat different meaning than it may have had in the old country.

Answer (score 2):

GDoS has the following early usage examples: 
***[stick a pin (in) there!](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/jo567zq#p5vqryq)***

> wait! hold it!
>
> - 1718    [UK]    C. Hitchin Regulator.
>
> (also ***stick a pin in that! stick a pin here!***) note carefully! bear in mind!
>
> - 1836    [US]    Public Ledger (Phila.) 1 Nov. n.p.: *Why does money become scarce? Because the bankers cannot discount, says the merchant. Stick a pin there.*

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the comments that it comes from (at least the concept of) pinning it to a board/wall. Before the digital age, researching and investigating required more time and effort so you had to prioritize your ideas.  If you had something like a story lead (needing to talk to someone or find the right person to talk with), topic to better understand (a trip to the library), or testing the veracity of someone's story then you might literally or figuratively "pin" it on a wall, board, or mental map.  All of these things might be important tasks, but not practical in the moment.

Today, we can easily find more information than we can consume so it might not seem natural to think of having to delay topics, but if you visualize having to physically travel in order to get information, I think it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score -1):

It could also come from bobbin lace. It is made on a firm pillow with a pattern or pricking attached. After each stitch or small group of stitches you put a pin between the threads into the pillow. This keeps the stitches you just finished from coming undone.

Comment: Hi Shen, welcome to our site! I'd love to upvote your answer, but at the moment it's lacking any reference or authority to distinguish a potentially *correct* answer from mere personal opinion. Can you [edit] your post to add a link to something that confirms what you describe? Or do you have personal experience in making bobbin lace? [If so, add that information to your answer.] For further guidance on what we expect in an answer, see [answer] – and I also recommend taking our EL&U **[Tour]**.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

When I was a kid or at least a teen, and someone was conceited, (had a big head) or thought they were above everyone else, we would say “oh stick a pin in it” and walk away. It was meant to tell them that their heads were so big and needed to be deflated.

Comment: This appears to be a different meaning to the one asked for in the question.